# Visualforce Page Showing Record Field based on criteria

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

The end goal is to display a dynamic motivational piece made of text and images, on agents' homepage.. A manager would create a Motivational record and the record with a date of today would have the body displayed on the agent's homepage. This way, they could create motivationals for the week and the one for each would be displayed on it's day.

This being said, I created a visualforce page component for the homepage, a visualforce page that the component references, and a custom object for the manager to put together their motivational masterpiece.

I want the visualforce page to display the custom object's Body field. I want only the body of the Motivational with a date of today to be shown on the visualforce page.

Everywhere I look, I don't see info on how to make sort through existing records of an object and display the one meeting criteria.. It's all visualforce pages that are accessing record connected to where the page is called. But this situation is having the page on the homepage to display the record info...and sifting through records to find the ones meeting the criteria

Any ideas of how to make this happen? Does this make sense?